# Is the sum of all irrational numbers between two integers rational?

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

> Is the sum of all irrational numbers between any two integer constants rational?

I think it should be, because every irrational number should have another irrational with which it would sum to a rational number (e.g. 3.141... sums with 3.858..., and 2.718... with 2.281...).

Why is this or isn't this a reasonable conclusion?

Comment: As stated, the question is meaningless. The sum of all irrational numbers is _infinite_, and infinity is not a number. (A more interesting question would be: If you take all irrational numbers in between 0 and 1, and you _averaged_ them, is the average rational? Answer: Yes, for basically the reason you gave. The average is 0.5, by the way.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw even I feel so its meaningless.

Comment: @columbus8myhw, I noted your comment and edited the text to more accurately reflect my question.

Comment: Well, the sum is _still_ infinite, but the _average_ is finite. (Although, it's not immediately obvious what "the average of an infinite amount of numbers" means...)

Comment: The sum may be infinitely large, but I think my logic holds that it should be the sum of infinitely many irrationals, each of which has a paired irrational with which it sums to a rational. And if that's true, can't you deduce that every term in that sum will be rational and so although it's infinitely large it will be a rational number as the terms in the sum approach infinity?

Comment: Also, if the average is rational, and the average is the sum itself divided by the number of terms in the sum, doesn't that necessitate that the sum is also rational, because the number of terms must be rational and if the average is rational then the numerator of the average (the sum) must be rational?

Comment: Danny. Sum of irrational numbers between some interval is not defined. Even if it's somehow defined, your reasoning would not hold. You basically write every term in your sum a difference between two numbers. Intuitively speaking, if you sum this two new numbers separately, can you guarantee that both of them would still be a number?

Comment: @Danny:  So are you asserting that the infinite sum of rational numbers $-1+1/2-1/3+1/4-1/5+1/6....$ must be rational?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition is only done between pairs of numbers: you can add $a$ and $b$ to obtain $a+b$.  We can extend this to sums of more than two numbers because addition is *associative* and *commutative*: when adding $a,b, $ and $c$ we don't have to worry about whether we want $(a+b)+c$ or $a+(b+c)$ or $(b+c) + a$ or whatever because the answer is always the same.

In *some* cases we can even extend this notion of summation to certain infinite sums.  For example, there is a well-defined sense in which $$1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots = 2$$  because we can consider the sequence $1, 1+\frac12, 1+\frac12+\frac14,\ldots$ and show that it approaches 2 from below.

However, none of this is any help in adding up all the irrational numbers, even those between two integers, because the irrational numbers have a property called *uncountability*: however you consider an infinite sum $i_1, i_1+i_2, i_2+i_2+i_3, \ldots$ of irrational numbers, you must always omit some irrational numbers from your list $i_1, i_2, i_3, \ldots$.  In fact you must omit *most* irrational numbers.  So the idea "sum of all the irrational numbers" simply has no mathematical meaning. The notion of addition does not extend to adding up that many things.

Even for relatively well-behaved sets like the set of all rational numbers (which are *not* uncountable), there is no clear notion of the sum of all the members of the set.  It can be shown that by ordering the rational numbers in the correct order $r_1, r_2, r_3, \ldots$, one can make the sums $r_1, r_1+r_2, r_1+r_2+r_3$ approach *any* desired target, or diverge to infinity.

If one considers just the set of rationals between 0 and 1, as you suggested, the sum diverges to infinity.  To see this, suppose the sum of all rational numbers between 0 and 1 added up to some number $S$.  Now consider the following sums:
$$ \begin{align}
S_1 &  = \frac12 + \frac14+\frac18 + \cdots &&= 1 \\
S_3 & = \frac35 + \frac3{10}+\frac3{20} + \cdots &&= \frac65 \\
S_5 & = \frac59 + \frac5{18}+\frac5{26} + \cdots &&= \frac {10}9 \\
&\vdots
\end{align}
$$

All together, $S_1, S_3, S_5, \ldots$ include only *some* of the rational numbers between 0 and 1, so $S$ must be bigger than $S_1$, it must be bigger than $S_1+S_3$, it must be bigger than $S_1+S_3+S_5$, and so on.  But since each of the $S_1, S_3, S_5,\ldots$ is at least 1, this shows that $S$ must be bigger than 1, bigger than 2, bigger than 3, and so on.  Since there is no such number $S$, it is not the case that the sum of all rational numbers is a number, and it does not make sense to ask whether that number is rational or irrational, because there is no such number.

So in mathematics as it is normally practiced at present, your question doesn't make sense and has no answer, neither 'yes' nor 'no'.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand, but I believe the uncountability argument only extends for ALL irrationals, correct? If I'm only talking about the irrationals between 1 and 2, I see no reason why I couldn't index them with natural numbers to infinity. I see clearly now why the set of all irrationals is uncountable (because they can't be indexed with real numbers), but I don't see why all irrationals between two constants (like 1 and 2) can't be indexed by infinitely many real numbers and therefore added.

Comment: @Danny, on the contrary, if the irrationals in $[1,2]$ were countable, then the set of *all* irrationals would be countable.  Try to show this as a good practice in relation to MJD's post.

Comment: I don't see how this is necessarily true.

Comment: @Danny. It is not easy to see actually. You need to find a function from irrationals in $[1,2]$ *onto* all irrational numbers. However if you do know that; deleting countable elements from an uncountable set still gives you an uncountable set, then the result follows from uncountability of real numbers between $0$ and $1$, which is much easier to see.

Comment: Correction: It should be "uncountability of real numbers between $1$ and $2$", not "uncountability of real numbers between $0$ and $1$".

Comment: @danny The irrationals between 1 and 2 are *also* uncountable. But even if they weren't, the question *still* wouldn't make sense, as I discussed in the following paragraph about the rational numbers, which are *not* uncountable. The uncountability just makes the problems with your question even wose.

Comment: I think I realize why all reals between 1 and 2 are uncountable, because there actually is no end so the literal act of indexing a real would omit a real preceding it -- you have to take steps of a certain size. MJD, I'm going to accept this as the answer but first would you care to explain to me what you meant with that second paragraph? I don't see how there is no notion of the sum of rationals between 1 and 2.

Comment: You probably *don't* realize why all reals between 1 and 2 are uncountable, because this term has a specific technical meaning that is not apparent, it is not something you can intuit, and your description of what you think is going on does not really make sense.  But I have tried to update the answer to explain why there is no number that is the sum of all the rationals between 1 and 2, and I hope it is some help.